# Finding a volume generated by a parabola

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, volume, solid-of-revolution

Below is a problem I did. The book gets $\frac{16\pi}{15}$.This number seems to large to me. I am hoping that somebody can confirm that I got it right or tell me where I went wrong.

Problem:

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given lines and curves about the x-axis.
$$ x = 1 - y^2 $$
$$ x = 0 $$

Answer:

First, I plot the function.
[A plot of the function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sqrt%281-x%29%2C%20-sqrt%281-x%29)

If you look at the plot, a rough estimate of the answer would be to treat it as a cylinder. Looking at the graph, a rough estimate of the radius of the cylinder would be $\frac{3}{4}$ and its height is $1$.
Therefore, a rough estimate of the answer would be $\pi ( \frac{3}{4} )^2 $ which is $\frac{9 \pi }{16}$.

Let $V$ be the volume we seek.
\begin{align*}
V &= \int_0^1 \pi y^2  \,\, dx \\
%
x - 1 &= -y^2 \\
y^2 &= 1 - x \\
V &= \int_0^1 \pi ( 1-x )  \,\, dx \\
V &= \pi \int_0^1  ( 1-x )  \,\, dx \\
\int_0^1  ( 1-x )  \,\, dx &= x - \frac{x^2}{2} \Big|_{0}^{1} = \frac{1}{2} \\
V &= \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

After double checking the book, I found that it says about the y-axis, not the x-axis. I am still hoping that somebody here can confirm that my work is right if you go about the x-axis.

Comment: The volume of revolution about the $y$-axis is $\frac{16\pi}{15}$.

Comment: I read / copied the question incorrectly.

Comment: @Sandejo If the question had said the x-axis, would my work be right?

Comment: That looks right. Good work. (For it to make sense, you'd have to change the bounding line $x=0$ into $y=0$, though.)

Comment: I also get your answer for rotation around the $x$ axis. You can use the same region as for the intended question; just be aware that if you rotate the region one complete turn around the $x$ axis, each point inside the volume gets swept through by the top half of the region **and** by the bottom half of the region. This could lead to double-counting, but fortunately you did not fall into that trap.